# Why does PHP not find the variable I'm referring to in this small code?

Tags: php

Why do I get 'undefined variable $image_src' with this code:

```
$image_src1=null;
$image_src2=null;
for ($i=1; $i<=$nr_of_pics; $i++) {
        $image_src.$i = $image_id.'_'.$i;
        }

    echo $image_src1;
```

I want the `$image_src.$i` to refer to the variable `$image_src1` or `$image_src2` depending on how many loops there are... But it wants to find the variable `$image_src` without an ending nr, which doesn't exist, because I want it to find the variable with the '$i' ending!

It doesn't get that the `$i` is for the last number in the variable `$image_src` name!

Rest of the code is fine!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to:

```
${'image_src' . $i} = $image_id . '_' . $i;
```

or you can also do it this way:

```
$var = 'image_src' . $i;
$$var = $image_id . '_' . $i;
```

See [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) from the PHP manual.

**Edit:** I'm assuming your question is a simplified example of your problem because of course you can always use arrays for this:

```
$image_src = array();
for ($i=1; $i<=2; $i++) {
  $image_src[$i] = $image_id . '_' . $i;
}
echo $image_src[1];
```

which makes more sense than variable variables for something like this.

Answer (score 5):

While others have correctly answered with `${"image_src$i"}`, I'd like to also recommend you use [arrays](http://php.net/array) for what you're trying to accomplish

```
$image_src = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $nr_of_pics; $i++) {
    $image_src[$i] = $image_id.'_'.$i;
}

echo $image_src[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try referring to it like this:

```
${"image_src$i"} = $image_id.'_'.$i;
```

or for readability (even though it isn't much better):

```
$name = "image_src".$i;
$$name = $image_id.'_'.$i;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this syntax,

```
    ${'image_src'.$i} = $image_id.'_'.$i;
```